# CSS Background design not working for IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background

I have the following code to design a background of a page:

```
body 
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 20%, circle farthest-side, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%), url('../images/background.png');
    background: radial-gradient(50% 20%, circle farthest-side, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%), url('../images/background.png');
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 20%, circle farthest-side, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%), url('../images/background.png');
    background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 20%, circle farthest-side, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%), url('../images/background.png');
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 20%, circle farthest-side, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%), url('../images/background.png');
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It is working for IE10 +, but how can we make it work for IE9 and IE8.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t329e50y/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In short: IE9 uses a totally different syntax from all other browsers or it's newer versions:

The CSS gradients had a lot of changes before they become candidate recommended (like 4 or 5 rewrites. The below code will work in almost all browser version.

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(153,218,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(153,218,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,128,128,1))); /* safari4+,chrome */
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(153,218,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(153,218,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(153,218,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%); /* ie10+ */
background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,218,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,128,1) 100%); /* w3c */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99DAFF', endColorstr='#008080',GradientType=1 ); /* ie6-9 */
```